# How to load date with 'dd/MM/yyyy' format in csv file in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

env: spark 2.4.5

I have a .csv file to be loaded and the date in it is of format 'dd/MM/yyyy', but this format date may can't be loaded correctly by spark.

I have tried those functions: `'to_date()', 'to_timestamp()', 'unix_timestamp()'`, but they all return 'null' with this format date. I would be very grateful if you could give me some suggestion.

Comment: I've found the solution here:

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201603.mbox/%3CCANe15CEwnaLidJJgyJfZjVDeoGJLoSThk+aujPndJMMe5sW+ew@mail.gmail.com%3E

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dateFormat` – sets the string that indicates a date format. Custom date formats follow the formats at java.text.SimpleDateFormat. This applies to date type. If None is set, it uses the default value, yyyy-MM-dd

try adding this option - `option("dateFormat", "dd/MM/yyyy")` to parse date columns in csv file.

CSV File Data

```
scala> "cat /tmp/sample.csv".!

"id","dt"
1,01/05/2020
2,20/04/2020
```

```
scala> val schema = DataType.fromJson("""{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"id","type":"integer","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"dt","type":"date","nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]}""").asInstanceOf[StructType]
schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(id,IntegerType,true), StructField(dt,DateType,true))

scala> schema.prettyJson
res26: String =
{
  "type" : "struct",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "id",
    "type" : "integer",
    "nullable" : true,
    "metadata" : { }
  }, {
    "name" : "dt",
    "type" : "date",
    "nullable" : true,
    "metadata" : { }
  } ]
}

scala> val df = spark
.read
.option("header","true")
.option("dateFormat", "dd/MM/yyyy") // add this to parse date values from csv file.
.schema(schema)
.format("csv").load("/tmp/sample.csv")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, dt: date]

scala> df.show(false)
+---+----------+
|id |dt        |
+---+----------+
|1  |2020-05-01|
|2  |2020-04-20|
+---+----------+


scala>
```

Comment: Thank you Srinivas :). It seems that "dateFormat" option must be used with schema to specify the column's type with ‘date’, right?

Comment: yes, if you are not specifying column datatype date in schema it will just import that column as type string.